# How do some people add stuff to their right of the user name in comments?

Tags: support, comments

I was reading through the [Formatting Sandobox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) here.

In the comments section of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59161/174964), there are some comments that contain some text to the right of the username.

Such as:

> Hello, I am Jon Skeet. ‮ teekS noJ - – Manishearth Mar 30 at 11:18

As a reply to a comment that asks how do they do that a user writes:

> Yay, I figured it out!! Copy the character inside the codeblock to get it it's a mirroring character. Note that the codeblock may have placed itself after my username. "‮‮ " – Manishearth Mar 27 at 12:43

But I don't understand.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I am not sure ...  ‮ ?ew naC

Comment: To clarify the comment, I'd supplied the character in the codeblock. ‮‮?huh ,looC

Comment: Actually, my attempt at identity theft would have worked better at Physics, where the comment-username link styling and normal link styling is the same. (Cue complete chaos and identity theft spree at Physics)

Comment: Whats cool is that Chrome's devtools are themselves webapps, so they get screwed by the character as well; and grokking how Panama and the rest did this magic was pretty hard (I knew it was a bidi thingy, but I first was looking for an unclosed bidi rtl span). All the devtools show is the mysterious `<naps/>` closing tag. :P

Comment: @Manishearth Actually that tag doesn't need a closing tag :) (it is a self-closing tag)

Comment: @AnishGupta: But naps have a duration! They must have open-close tags! And they must be nestable (seen _Inception_? ) :P

Comment: @Manishearth I don't get that. I didn't see Inception.

Comment: @AnishGupta: First thing, did you realize that `<naps/>` is `</span>` unicode-backwarded? Use Chrome, right click on Panama's comment (not mine, mine opens a new line and screws the effect), and inspect. There will be a mirrored span--> naps. As for my comment, I was saying that a "nap" (i.e. sleep), has a duration and thus does not qualify as a self-closing tag. And _Inception_ had to do with dreams-within-dreams-within-dreams, so I was saying that, in addition to being non-self-closing, they must be nestable ;-)

Comment: Random, bad, HTML joke, really :/

Comment: I realised that `naps` is `span` backwards. I did the Chrome thing when I read the question. Now I get the nap/sleep thing. I read the inception bit and thought it must be something to do with the movie.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Just to let you know, [downvotes work slightly differently here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Manishearth: ‮. ti daer I wonk I‮

Comment: Why more down votes ?

Comment: @AnishGupta see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131802/how-do-some-people-add-stuff-to-their-right-of-the-user-name-in-comments/131803#comment364008_131802

Comment: @amanaP I read that already and I wrote that recently

Comment: @AnishGupta but yet you make the same comment...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a unicode (`RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE`) hack:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm

Comment: It can be used in the SO comments. ‮ :-)

Comment: You're abusing that with your user name! Nice! :D

Comment: All is fair here in the comments @LukasEder ‮

Comment: Please note that while a certain degree of fun and games are allowed on Meta, true to its lighthearted spirit, **stuff like this will not be looked on kindly if you try it on Stack Overflow**.

Comment: How can you write it do you write it as `&#202E`

Comment: @AnishGupta I use the decimal version. I do: `ALT` + (`08238`) ‮

Comment: Hmmm.... ‮Does this work?

Comment: That seemed to do it! ‮

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Yes, especially since it can be used to spoof usernames on sites where the link style is the same. http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389/formatting-sandbox/1270#comment2988_1270

Comment: @Seth I am not sure what you are trying...‮

Comment: ‮You guys are seriously weird.  ‭‮  Seriously....‭You guys are seriously weird.

Comment: Go to https://unicode-table.com/en/#202E and copy. That is the easiest way. `RTLO is used on the right. ‮This is the most entertaining way to type.`

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a website](http://digitalpbk.blogspot.in/2006/11/fun-with-unicode-and-mirroring.html) which you can directly copy it from instead of having to mess around with hex codes:

Copy the character from between the parentheses

(‮‮(

I think it's better to copy the parentheses themselves, and then remove them one by one. You may have to use your keyboard arrow keys for this, since the bidi character is invisible even when selected. It takes some practice and you have to realise that sometimes you need to move the arrow keys in the *other* direction.

Comment: It doesn't work in chrome :(

Comment: @AnishGupta: Clarified

Comment: ‮‮‮won gnitset :) skrow tI

Comment: @AnishGupta: ‮‮!eikooc a evaH !og ay erehT

Comment: What's a bidi character?

Comment: @AnishGupta: Bidi=[BiDirectional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) . Some languages like Hebrew and Arabic write right to left. There's some CSS that can help here, and a bunch of Unicode overrides like the one above.

Comment: Thanks! `The comment needs to be at least 15 characters so I'm adding all this junk`

Comment: @ani - or just use a few zero width Unicode characters - pick it up from in between the brackets --> (​)...

Comment: :) ​​ ​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Lix I'm aware of them but I couldn't be bothered to find them online

Comment: @lix I was trying to use em recently, but all my efforts of copying the character failed. I finally scripted it :p

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Love this. ‮‮It is awesome!

Comment: The website has been completely deleted apparently, Verizon says it couldn't find the site.

Comment: Wow, very cool, ‮‮Look at this