# U+202e in a chat message messes up the starred messages list

Tags: bug, chat, unicode

I'm sure the devs will be thrilled to have *yet another* case for which to test:

[image: Buggered up wall]

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6965398#6965398

Comment: Same issue as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131818/kill-unicode-bidirectional-override-in-comments, except in the chat sidebar.

Comment: @Anna any plans to filter out such characters?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No idea. Maybe? I mean, this is kind of a case of "doctor, it hurts when I do this". :) We potentially have chat rooms where RTL is the way to go, so filtering that *out* is likely a non-starter.

Answer (score 8):

Oh, the folks at MSO found out about it waaay before the XKCD post:

[First appearance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/59161#59161)

[Post asking how it's done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131802/how-do-some-people-add-stuff-to-their-right-of-the-user-name-in-comments/131816#comment364014_131816)

[Post asking it to be removed as it can be abused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131818/kill-unicode-bidirectional-override-in-comments)

It really can't be abused in chat. In comments, you can impersonate people with it, but not in chat (except in the starred list). Since the devs aren't really bothered about it being there in comments, I doubt they will be bothered it being in chat. So, no biggie.

Comment: I'm not even so sure about the significance of using this to impersonate people in comments. The comment signature looks different - badly formatted, "wrong" compared to the other comments, etc. You'd do a far better job with just changing your username.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Well, people as in mods. If you see the third post, changing your username to something like "yadoT" and then using the bidi character for impersonation can make the comment look like it comes from a mod (except under close inspection) on sites with uniform link formatting.

Comment: I'm looking at [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131818/kill-unicode-bidirectional-override-in-comments#comment364052_131819) and it seems painfully obvious to me that it's not real. Not 100% sure if that's because there are others around it and/or I know what to look for, though. Either way, aside from causing some easily correctable verbal damage, it's not like someone can *actually* become a moderator this way. At worst, this seems like an annoyance.

Comment: @AnnaLear: That's on meta. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389/formatting-sandbox/1270#comment2988_1270, with some work you can make it look like http://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBl4.png. True, you can only impersonate a mod and do nothing else. It's not that big a problem :)